# Firebase toDate() use CEST instead of localTime

Tags: javascript, firebase, date, time

I am using firebase `toDate()`-method to get a Date object from my timestamp:

```
myTimestamp.toDate()
```

This creates a `Date`-object (which I need), but in local time (the time my operating system uses). How can I get it to give me a `Date`-Object in CEST/CET?

*edit:*
The timestamp comes from [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp.html#toDate()) and I am using their `toDate()` method.

Comment: Of what type is `myTimestamp`? AFAIK there is no built-in object in JavaScript itself that exposes a `toDate` method. Also, `Date` objects are always in local time -- see [Get date time for a specific time zone using JavaScript](//stackoverflow.com/q/11124322) for how to convert.

Comment: @HereticMonkey—[*Date objects*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date-objects) are always UTC, they convert to/from local when presenting/parsing strings.

Comment: Duplicate of [*Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript?s=1|192.4542)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integer value contained by a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object (milliseconds since unix epoch) is not affected by timezones.  It represents the same point in time for all people on the planet.

However, when you print a Date object, you will see the date rendered with local timezone.  If you want just that integer number inside the Date, call getTime() on it for use elsewhere.

You can feed a Date (or the underlying number) to other libraries that may do what you really want with the date, including [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) with [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).  For example, this may work with moment:

```
moment(your_date).tz('Desired Timezone').format('ha z')
```

Comment: Without a library there is `new Date().toLocaleString('de',{timeZone: 'Europe/Berlin', timeZoneName:'short'})` but support for [IANA timezone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) is fairly new. ;-)

Comment: @RobG somehow this line of code doesn't change my date object at all. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: @progNewbie—it may be that the host doesn't support the *timeZone* option, see the [*MDN compatibility chart*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#Browser_compatibility). It seems to work in the most recent Chrome, Firefox and Safari and produces "6.9.2018, 02:48:44 MESZ". Using en-GB and Chile/EasterIsland produces "05/09/2018, 19:48:44 GMT-5" in Firefox and Safari, but Chrome throws a range error, it doesn't support that timezone name.

Comment: Firebase functions support timezone but unfortunately not the first parameter to do with localization.